# Remove underline from menus and links

Tags: css

I am on the URL [dev2one website](http://dev2one.com/?lang=fr)
and all the menus and links are underlined

I add the CSS codes: `text-decoration: none;` in the body, but still the same.

Any idea how it works on each of the menus for example, but not on the body level

thanks

Answer (score 4):

You should add it to your `a` elements:

```
.main-navigation > div > ul > li > a {

    text-decoration: none;
    /* other styles...*/

}
```

When setting it on `body` it has no effect on `a` elements because the **browser default styles** are applied

```
body {
   text-decoration: none;        /* will have no effect on <a> elements since: */
}

a:-webkit-any-link {             /* user agent stylesheet */
    color: -webkit-link;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: underline;  /* NOTICE THIS! */
}

/* let's override user agent stylesheet */

.main-navigation li  a {
    text-decoration: none; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add CSS code to remove underlines

```
.main-navigation > div > ul > li > a{
    text-decoration: none;
}
```